# Player Swipe Movement Controller like subway surfer using Character Controller in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a player movement controller like subway surfer using Character Controller, every thing is working fine with keyboard but I am getting an issue in swipe. When I swipe its moving only one frame. And also I want player to go left and right while player in air(Jumping). Please help.

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerControllerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 8.0F;
    public float jumpSpeed = 16.0F;
    public float gravity = 80.0F;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

    public int laneNumber = 1;
    public int lanesCount = 3;
    bool didChangeLastFrame = false;
    public float laneDistance = 2;
    public float firstLaneXPos = -2;
    public float deadZone = 0.1f;
    public float sideSpeed = 12;
    private bool Right = false;
    private bool Left = false;


    void Update()
    {
        CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        float input = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        if (controller.isGrounded) {
            if (Mathf.Abs(input) > deadZone)
            {
                if (!didChangeLastFrame)
                {
                    didChangeLastFrame = true;
                    laneNumber += Mathf.RoundToInt(Mathf.Sign(input));
                    if (laneNumber < 0) laneNumber = 0;
                    else if (laneNumber >= lanesCount) laneNumber = lanesCount - 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                didChangeLastFrame = false;

                moveDirection = new Vector3(0, 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
                moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
                moveDirection *= speed;

                if (Input.GetButton("Jump") || SwipeManager.IsSwipingUp())
                    moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
            }
        }

        if (Left)
            moveDirection.x = -jumpSpeed;

        if (Right)
            moveDirection.x = jumpSpeed;

        if (SwipeManager.IsSwipingLeft())
        {
            Left = true;
            Right = false;
        }

        if (SwipeManager.IsSwipingRight())
        {
            Right = true;
            Left = false;
        }

        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        pos.x = Mathf.Lerp(pos.x, firstLaneXPos + laneDistance * laneNumber, Time.deltaTime * sideSpeed);
        transform.position = pos;

        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Move `CharacterController controller` to `private` field of your  `PlayerControllerScript` script for better perfomance. Since it doesn't change. And make `controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();` in `Start()`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I moved it to Start(), Can help me with the question I asked? @KamikyIT

Answer (score 0):

I think,

`if (Input.GetButton("Jump") || SwipeManager.IsSwipingUp())
                    moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;` 
must be outside the if(controller.isGrounded) block. So, you jump regardless of gravity.
This is the final code;

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerControllerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed = 8.0F;
public float jumpSpeed = 16.0F;
public float gravity = 80.0F;
private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

public int laneNumber = 1;
public int lanesCount = 3;
bool didChangeLastFrame = false;
public float laneDistance = 2;
public float firstLaneXPos = -2;
public float deadZone = 0.1f;
public float sideSpeed = 12;
private bool Right = false;
private bool Left = false;


void Update()
{
    CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

    float input = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    if (controller.isGrounded) {
        if (Mathf.Abs(input) > deadZone)
        {
            if (!didChangeLastFrame)
            {
                didChangeLastFrame = true;
                laneNumber += Mathf.RoundToInt(Mathf.Sign(input));
                if (laneNumber < 0) laneNumber = 0;
                else if (laneNumber >= lanesCount) laneNumber = lanesCount - 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            didChangeLastFrame = false;

            moveDirection = new Vector3(0, 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
            moveDirection *= speed;
        }
    }

    if (Input.GetButton("Jump") || SwipeManager.IsSwipingUp())
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;

    if (Left)
        moveDirection.x = -jumpSpeed;

    if (Right)
        moveDirection.x = jumpSpeed;

    if (SwipeManager.IsSwipingLeft())
    {
        Left = true;
        Right = false;
    }

    if (SwipeManager.IsSwipingRight())
    {
        Right = true;
        Left = false;
    }

    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
    pos.x = Mathf.Lerp(pos.x, firstLaneXPos + laneDistance * laneNumber, Time.deltaTime * sideSpeed);
    transform.position = pos;

    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
}
```